Prove product of $L_1$ function and bounded function is $L_1$ with $L_1$ space defined as completion
The following question arises from reading Barry Simon's ''Comprehensive course in analysis''. First, there is strictly positive linear functional $\ell: C_{\mathbb{R}}(X) \to \mathbb{R}$ where $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space. Then we define metric on $C_\mathbb{{R}}(X)$ as $\|f\|_\ell = \ell(|f|)$. (Abstract) $L_1$ space then would be the completion of $C_\mathbb{{R}}(X)$ with respect to this metric.
The question that bothers me is one of the facts given in the book, which is trivial under classical definition of $L_1$ space, but kinda obscure in Simon's setting. There it is: if you take $L_1$ functions $f$ and bounded $g$ (you can say it is the limit of universally bounded Cauchy sequence of continious functions), then $fg$ must be $L_1$. Can it be proved without involving any complex theorems? I tried to prove at least the fact that given ${f_n}$ approximating $f$ and ${g_n}$ approximating $g$ (universally bounded), ${f_n g_n}$ will be Cauchy, but failed at proving $\|f_m(g_n - g_m)\|_\ell < \epsilon$ for large enough $n$ and $m$.

For $f,g\in C(X)$ there holds $$l(|fg|)\le |g|_\infty l(|f|)$$ This should help.

@RyszardSzwarc I just can't convince myself this is enough for rigorous proof, since $f$ and $g$ aren't really functions. How do you prove $fg$ exists without proving $f_n g_n$ is Cauchy?

$f_ng_n-f_mg_m=(f_n-f_m)g_n+(g_n-g_m)f_m$ Hence $$l(|f_ng_n-f_mg_m|)\le |g_n|\infty l(|f_n-f_m|)+|g_n-g_m|\infty l(|f_m|)$$

@RyszardSzwarc And how $|g_n - g_m|_\infty$ convergence to zero follows from its $\ell$-convergence to zero?

How is this a metric ?

@Maxime Sorry, I forgot to add that functional is linear. Then properties of metric are straighforward (and it is not just semimetric due to strictly positivity of functional)

I am not sure why the triangular inequality holds..?

@Maxime Because $\ell(|f + g|) \leq \ell(|f|) + \ell(|g|)$ by linearity, positivity of $\ell$ and triangle inequality in $\mathbb{R}$

Right, I was confused about what you meant by positivity of a functional ;)
